# DataReader slow

Tags: c#, data-binding, ado.net

I have a `DataReader` that populates a `GridView`, but it's very slow.

I load 5000 rows. When I run the query on SQL with SSMS, it's done in 1-5, seconds but with the browser it takes 30-45 Seconds :/

How can I improve this to be faster?

My code:

```
public SqlDataReader MostraVistoriaOpereracionalAdmin(String data1, String data2, string todos)
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), data, 103) AS 'Data', " +
    "motorista AS 'Motorista', "+
    "ajudante1 AS 'Ajudante I', "+
    "ajudante2 AS 'Ajudante II', "+
    "CASE WHEN os = 0 THEN 'Não' WHEN os = 1 THEN 'Sim' END AS' OS ', "+
    "CASE WHEN mtr = 0 THEN 'Não' WHEN mtr = 1 THEN 'Sim' END AS 'MTR', "+
    "CASE WHEN roteiro = 0 THEN 'Não' WHEN roteiro = 1 THEN 'Sim' END AS 'Roteiro', "+
    "CASE WHEN final = 0 THEN 'Não' WHEN final = 1 THEN 'Sim' END AS 'Dest. Final', "+
    "os  * -1 + mtr * -5 + roteiro * -3 + final * -10000 AS 'pontos', "+ // Faz o calculo da pontuação
    "gravado_por AS 'Gravado Por', "+
    "gravado_em AS 'Gravado Em' " +
    "FROM tbl_vistoria WHERE data BETWEEN '"+data1+"' AND '"+data2+"'";

    if (todos != "TODOS")
    {
        sql += " AND (motorista = '"+todos+"' OR ajudante1 = '"+todos+"' OR ajudante2 = '"+todos+"')";
    }

    sql += "ORDER BY tbl_vistoria.data";

    command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
    return dataReader;

}
```

My action in the `Button`. It calls the `DataReader`:

```
VistoriaDB vistoriaDB = new VistoriaDB();
grvOperacional.DataSource = vistoriaDB.MostraVistoriaOpereracionalAdmin(d1, d2, funcionario);
grvOperacional.DataBind();
```

Comment: Why do you want to show 5000 records in a GridView? Are you at least using paging in the grid? Every record will cause the grid to generate a tablerow in a html-table which must be sent to the client and rendered by the browser. The easiest would be to enable paging in this case.

Comment: Do some debugging to find the bottleneck.  Is the read from the database the slow part?  Something in the code between the database and the UI?  A large amount of data being sent to the browser?  Slow JavaScript on the page?  You need to find the slow part before you can address the cause.

Comment: No ... The users don't like the pagination :/

Comment: Also, from the looks of this code, there's a *very good* chance that you're exposing a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @Pedro: Then tell the users that ASP.NET is not Winforms and all the data must be sent through your network two times, first from database to webserver and second from iis to the client.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the customer is always right!

Comment: I have the same problem as the asker; I did extensive debug, and the bottleneck *is* in the datareader: `Console.WriteLine($"Getter executed: {sw.Elapsed} = 00:00:00.3802027."); while (result.Read()) { results.Add((Guid) result[0]); } Console.WriteLine($"Getter built: {sw.Elapsed} = 00:00:11.8836770.");`

Comment: Well, my bottleneck was not in the db_reader. The query itself was heavy, and some polishing improved its performance by almost 3 orders of magnitude. ‍♀️